# Programmatically show tooltip after an ajax call

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a plugin or a tutorial on how to trigger a tooltip after an ajax call. At the moment I'm using [jQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/any-html.html) to create the tooltips. But I don't want the tooltips to trigger on a mouseOver event; rather, I want them to show after an ajax call. I can't find any documentation or examples on how to achieve this. For example:

```
<a class="vote">Vote</a>

<div id="tooltip">
Some tooltip with a message.
</div>

$.ajax({
    context: this,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.result == "success") {
// SHOW TOOL TIP HERE
        } 
        else {
// SHOW ANOTHER TOOL TIP HERE
            }
        });
```

The way jQuery Tools works is by simply binding the element to the tool tip as such: (but this causes the tooltip to open on mouseOver)

```
$("#myElement").tooltip();
```

There is an API with events included in jQuery tools, but I have no clue how to only show the tooltip after the Ajax! Another complicating factor is the I need to have the same tooltip (or multiple tooltips) appear on multiple elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an example of how to show a 'tooltip' or a popup dialog after some event. No ajax here, but just using the click action of the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#vote").click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        // Do your ajax
        // Show the popup
        $("#tooltip").show();
    });

    $("#tooltip").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tm8Lr/1/

Hope this helps you get started.

Bob

Comment: Thanks rcraves. I actually got the tooltip to show and hide. The only trick is to make it's position relative to the link being clicked. (I have multiple vote-links on the page.)

Answer (score 19):

Does it not work to simply trigger the mouseover event after binding the tooltip?

```
$('#myElement').tooltip().mouseover();
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [`tooltip` documentation](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html) (especially the [scripting API](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html#api)) and the [how their API works](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/scripting.html).

So it should work with:

```
if (response.result == "success") {
    $('#myElement').data('tooltip').show();
} 
else {
    // don't know which other tooltip you want to show here
}
```

[You can also specify at which events the tooltip should be shown](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html#callbacks) (so you probably can exclude `mouseover` or change it to something that you know is never triggered on that element (like `change`)).

Comment: @felix , nice answer , i didn't look at tooltip api, in my project i wrote my own custom tooltip , thats why i gave answer like that

Comment: Felix, thanks for the response. One of the issues that I failed to mention (until I update the question) was having multiple elements that require the tooltip. Can the tooltip be reusable in anyway, or do I have to create a new tooltip for each element? I think the data('tooltip') is only bound to one element.

Comment: @mel you can give a common class name to all the elements you want and use that , that should fix your problem

Comment: @Mel: Yes it is only bound to one element. Maybe you have to do it for every element individually. But I don't know for sure, I have no experience with the plugin. This is just what I found in the documentation.

Comment: @gov: Not necessarily: *`data(key)`: Returns value at named data store for the **first element** in the jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value).*

Answer (score 2):

You can use trigger function to start other function binded to mouseOver.

```
$('#ElemWithTootip').trigger('mouseOver');
```

Answer (score 1):

Mel,

You can write your own tooltip , tooltips are nothing but div boxes with custom look and feel and then absolutely positioned.

Once your ajax completes show the tooltip by jquerys show

```
$('#tooltipid').show();
```

if you want to hide after few seconds you can do that also using jquery or javascripts setTimeout();

I think all you want is , once ajax completes you have some new html in the dom and you want to show some popup above that code right ,

Hope this helps

Comment: gov, many thanks. I thought about that. But since I have many elements on the page that require this, it seems really tricky to position it next the element being clicked on.

Comment: @Mel thats cool , but i think you can use the same api to do a .show() did it work for you